# How do I unlock a Windows 10 RDP session (not the console)?

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop, lock-screen

I am RDPing to a Windows 10 Pro machine. Some file transfer is set running and left to do its thing.

Once the machine has locked the only option available is to disconnect the session and then reconnect, there appears to be no way to unlock the machine. The background is shown as a blur, with the accessibility and power icons in the bottom right. No user or login information is shown. Ctrl-Alt-Del is required for this machine, but this information is not displayed and Ctrl-Alt-End does nothing (but works outside of this scenario).

Is there a way to either unlock the RDP session, or prevent the lock happening, without impacting the way the machine operates from the console?

Comment: You might find TightVNC an easier solution. Install it on your sender and set a VNC password. Then install it on the receiver and use TightVNC Viewer to log into the sender with IP address. The session should stay open and if windows locks you should still be able to see the login screen as if you were a local user.